# How are django variable tags used within html templates?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

When writing .html files the variable tags "{{" "}}" do not display any information when rendered. 
example:

//model.py

```
 class model_name(models.Model):
     name_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, name='Name')
     link_id = models.CharField(max_length=4, name='Link')
```

//tables.py

```
class model_name_table(tables.Table):
    column_name = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{{model_name.link_id}}">{{model_name.name_id}}text_for_example</a>')

    class Meta:
        model = model_name
        fields = ('column_name', 'Name')
```

This yields "text_for_example" when rendered but neither {{model_name.link_id}} or {{model_name.name_id}} display anything.

Simplifying to:

```
class model_name_table(tables.Table):
    column_name = tables.TemplateColumn('{{model_name.name_id}}')

    class Meta:
        model = model_name
        fields = ('column_name', 'Name')
```

Yields blank data within the column. How are variable tags supposed to be used to render data from models?

django-tables2 reference
http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#templatecolumn

djagno template language reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django-tables2 documentation you link to show exactly where you're going wrong: the context item that contains the current row is called `record`, not `model_name`.

```
column_name = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{{record.link_id}}">{{record.name_id}}text_for_example</a>')
```

Comment: Thank you. using record.link_id and record.name_id did not work, however changing it to record.Name and record.Link did.